# Giving Object's Property through scanf

Tags: c

Code:

```
RectangleCorner *corner1 = [RectangleCorner new];
printf("Enter first corner coordinates \n");

float u1 = corner1.x;
float i1 = corner1.y;

scanf("%f;%f", &u1, &i1);
printf("%f; %f", &u1, &i1);
```

After entering values (e.g 7;5) still prints out "0.00000; 0.00000"

Why the assignment of the values didn't happen?

Comment: Look up how printf works.

Comment: remove `&`. e.g `printf("%f; %f", u1, i1);`

Comment: thank you. copy pasted from `scanf` with ampersands. Such thing usually indicates "enough xcode" for today.

Comment: Check the return value from scanf() to ensure you got 2 values scanned.

Answer (score 1):

credit to @BLUEPIXY: 
I simply had to remove the ampersand signs from the printf statement: 
`printf("%f; %f", u1, i1);`